# delete items from a list that equals to index of other list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 2 lists :

```
<ul id="listone">
<li><input type="checkbox"/>item 1</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"/>item 2</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"/>item 3</li>
</ul>


<ul id="listtwo">
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to uncheck an item from list one so it finds the exact value in list two and deletes the value from list two.

I'm trying to assign list two items an id that equals to the index number of item 1 when its unchecked and delete the item in list two the has an id = index of items I unchecked from list one. this is my code so far :

```
$("input.selectme").bind('change',function() {
    var ix = $(this).index(".selectme");
    //var panelix = $("#panel ol li span").html();
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');   
    var fileurl = $(this).next("label").attr("rel");
    var filename = $(this).next("label").text().replace("&nbsp;","").trim();
    var getlength = $(".fileslist li").length;


            if(checked===true) {                
                $("#panel ol").prev("h5").html("Your list currently has:");
                curl = localStorage.curl="<div class='delete'><\/div><li id="+ix+"><a href='"+fileurl+"'>"+filename+"<\/a><\/li>";
                $("#panel ol").append(localStorage.curl); //creating a new item in the list
                $("#panel .btn").css("display","block");


            }
            else{   
            //ix = $(this).index();             
            for(i=0;i<$("#panel ol li").length;i++){                                
                if(ix === $(this).attr("id")){
                    alert("pl");
                    $(this).css("color","red");

                    }                   
                $(this).attr("id",ix).css("border","solid 1px red");

                }
```

I can't get that to work... any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance

Comment: Data-binding would help a lot here, IMO

Comment: What do u mean by `uncheck` a `li` ?

Answer (score 1):

checkboxtry this:

```
<ul id="listone">
<li><input type="checkbox" class='chk' value="item1"/>item 1</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class='chk' value="item2"/>item 2</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class='chk' value="item3"/>item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listtwo">
<li class="list_item1">item 1</li>
<li class="list_item2">item 2</li>
<li class="list_item3">item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listThree">
<li class="list_item1">other item 1</li>
<li class="list_item2">other item 2</li>
<li class="list_item3">other item 3</li>
</ul>

    $(".chk").click(function () {
            var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if (!isChecked) {
                var itemId = $(this).val();
                $(".list_" + itemId).hide();
            }          
        });
```

Comment: i used this : 'else{ 
   var len = $("#sidelist li").length();
   
   for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    var itemId = $(this).index();
     $("li#"+itemId).remove();
    $("li#"+itemId).prev(".delete")
    }'  but only deletes the first item and ignores the rest when i try to uncheck an item it doesnt delte it

Comment: the else is just if its checked do this else delete the item from list

Comment: its from my code i just used the 'var itemId = $(this).val();
                $("#listTwo_" + itemId).hide();'  from your code

Comment: this code is goiing to run for unchecked items. check << ! >> in if statement!

Comment: i want to delete the items from list two when i unchek actually the items in list one , your code runs fine for me but it removes only the 1st item that has index = 0 but doesn't work with all other items in the list

Comment: hmmm... os you have some other items (like item2) in different places and you want all of those to remove. am  i right?

Comment: ok for that ... I have to change the code a little. check it out.

Comment: i finally reached the solution which very easy it was to just put: $(".list"+ix).remove();  - im really sorry its so stupid from me it was that easy and couldnt fix it , thanks alot for inspiring me.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `li` elements in the second list the index will no longer match, instead I'd suggest:

```
$('#listone input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var prop = text = this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#listtwo li').filter(function(){
            return text === $.trim($(this).text());
        }).remove();
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qdNNh/).